# The asset moves faster than its parent b2Body in AS3,Box2d

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, flash-cs5

I am trying to create a snowboarder which would just surf through slopes. But when i run the project, the asset which i added runs faster that it's parent body. It just runs out of the bounds of the b2Body. Why does it happen even after setting its positions with respect to it's parent b2body.  Here's the code which i used. Not to mention i am new to Box2d.

```
 package  {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import Box2D.Collision.*;
        import Box2D.Common.*;
        import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
        import Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.*;
        import Box2D.Dynamics.Contacts.*;
        import Box2D.Common.Math.*;
        import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
        import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
        import flash.display.Shape;

        public class PhysSnowboarder extends Sprite {
            //Degree to Radian Constant
            private const degreesToRadians:Number=0.0174532925;

            //World Definition
            public var worldScale:Number=30;
            private var world:b2World= new b2World(new b2Vec2(0,9.8),true);

            //Key Flags (Game Control Keys)
            private var left:Boolean=false;
            private var right:Boolean=false;

            //Hill attributes and misc
            private var nextHill:Number=240;
            private var realHeight:Number=240;
            private var realWidth:Number=0;
            private var buildNextHillAt:Number=0;


            //Sphere
            var theSphere:b2Body;
            var riderBody:b2Body;
            //Game Canvas
            private var gameCanvas:Sprite= new Sprite();

            public function PhysSnowboarder(){
                // i created a simple image of a snowboarder, created an as linkage. 
                        // Inherits flash.display.sprite

                var boardRider:BoardRider= new BoardRider();

                //create a sphere
                var sphereShape:b2CircleShape= new b2CircleShape(50/worldScale);
                var sphereFixture:b2FixtureDef= new b2FixtureDef();
                sphereFixture.density=2;
                sphereFixture.friction=3;
                sphereFixture.restitution=0.1;
                //sphereFixture.filter.groupIndex=-1;
                sphereFixture.shape=sphereShape;


                //sphere body 
                var sphereBodyDef:b2BodyDef= new b2BodyDef();
                sphereBodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
                sphereBodyDef.position.Set(320/worldScale,0);
                sphereBodyDef.userData=new Object();
                sphereBodyDef.userData.asset=boardRider;

                //Add the sphere to stage
                theSphere=world.CreateBody(sphereBodyDef);
                theSphere.SetUserData(sphereBodyDef.userData);
                theSphere.CreateFixture(sphereFixture);
                addChild(sphereBodyDef.userData.asset);
                //theSphere.SetUserData(boardRider);
                //addChild(theSphere.GetUserData());

                addChild(gameCanvas);
                //stage.addChild(new ());

                debugDraw();
                while(realWidth<1280){
                    nextHill=drawHill(5,realWidth,nextHill);

                }
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateWorld);
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressed);
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyReleased);

            }

            //debugDraw
            private function debugDraw():void{
                var worldDebugDraw:b2DebugDraw= new b2DebugDraw();
                var debugSprite:Sprite=  new Sprite();
                gameCanvas.addChild(debugSprite);

                worldDebugDraw.SetSprite(debugSprite);
                worldDebugDraw.SetDrawScale(worldScale);
                worldDebugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit|b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
                worldDebugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.5);
                world.SetDebugDraw(worldDebugDraw);
            }

            //drawHill 

            private function drawHill(pixelStep:int,xOffset:Number,yOffset:Number):Number{
                var hillStartY:Number=yOffset;
                var hillWidth:Number=120+Math.ceil(Math.random()*26)*20;
                realWidth+=hillWidth;

                var numberOfSlices=hillWidth/pixelStep;
                var hillVector:Vector.<b2Vec2>;
                var randomHeight:Number;

                if(xOffset==0){
                    randomHeight=0;
                }
                else{
                    do{
                        //randomHeight=Math.random()*hillWidth/7.5;
                        randomHeight=240/worldScale;
                    }while(realHeight+randomHeight>600);
                }

                realHeight+=randomHeight;
                hillStartY-=randomHeight;

                for (var j:int=0; j<numberOfSlices/2; j++) {
                    hillVector=new Vector.<b2Vec2>();
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2((j*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,480/worldScale));
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2((j*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,(hillStartY+randomHeight*Math.cos(2*Math.PI/numberOfSlices*j))/worldScale));
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2(((j+1)*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,(hillStartY+randomHeight*Math.cos(2*Math.PI/numberOfSlices*(j+1)))/worldScale));
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2(((j+1)*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,480/worldScale));
                    var sliceBody:b2BodyDef=new b2BodyDef  ;
                    var centre:b2Vec2=findCentroid(hillVector,hillVector.length);
                    sliceBody.position.Set(centre.x,centre.y);
                    for (var z:int=0; z<hillVector.length; z++) {
                        hillVector[z].Subtract(centre);
                    }
                    var slicePoly:b2PolygonShape=new b2PolygonShape  ;
                    slicePoly.SetAsVector(hillVector,4);
                    var sliceFixture:b2FixtureDef=new b2FixtureDef  ;
                    sliceFixture.shape=slicePoly;
                    var worldSlice:b2Body=world.CreateBody(sliceBody);
                    worldSlice.CreateFixture(sliceFixture);
                }
                hillStartY-=randomHeight;



                if (xOffset==0) {
                    randomHeight=0;
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        randomHeight=Math.random()*hillWidth/5;
                    } while (realHeight-randomHeight<240);
                }
                realHeight-=randomHeight;
                hillStartY+=randomHeight;

                for (j=numberOfSlices/2; j<numberOfSlices; j++) {
                    hillVector=new Vector.<b2Vec2>();
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2((j*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,480/worldScale));
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2((j*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,(hillStartY+randomHeight*Math.cos(2*Math.PI/numberOfSlices*j))/worldScale));
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2(((j+1)*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,(hillStartY+randomHeight*Math.cos(2*Math.PI/numberOfSlices*(j+1)))/worldScale));
                    hillVector.push(new b2Vec2(((j+1)*pixelStep+xOffset)/worldScale,480/worldScale));
                    sliceBody=new b2BodyDef  ;
                    centre=findCentroid(hillVector,hillVector.length);
                    sliceBody.position.Set(centre.x,centre.y);
                    for (z=0; z<hillVector.length; z++) {
                        hillVector[z].Subtract(centre);
                    }
                    slicePoly=new b2PolygonShape  ;
                    slicePoly.SetAsVector(hillVector,4);
                    sliceFixture=new b2FixtureDef  ;
                    sliceFixture.shape=slicePoly;
                    worldSlice=world.CreateBody(sliceBody);
                    worldSlice.CreateFixture(sliceFixture);
                }
                hillStartY=hillStartY+randomHeight;
                return (hillStartY);
            }

            //findCentroid
            private function findCentroid(vs:Vector.<b2Vec2>,count:uint):b2Vec2{
                var c:b2Vec2= new b2Vec2();
                var area:Number=0.0;
                var p1X:Number=0.0;
                var p1Y:Number=0.0;

                var inv3:Number=1.0/3.0;

                for(var i:int=0; i<count;++i){
                    var p2:b2Vec2=vs[i];
                    var p3:b2Vec2=i+1<count?vs[int(i+1)]:vs[0];

                    var e1X:Number=p2.x-p1X;
                    var e1Y:Number=p2.y-p1Y;

                    var e2X:Number=p3.x-p1X;
                    var e2Y:Number=p3.y-p1Y;

                    var D:Number=(e1X*e2Y-e1Y*e2X);
                    var triangleArea:Number=0.5*D;

                    area+=triangleArea;
                    c.x+=triangleArea*inv3*(p1X+p2.x+p3.x);
                    c.y+=triangleArea*inv3*(p1Y+p2.y+p3.y);

                    }
                    c.x*=1.0/area;
                    c.y*=1.0/area;

                    return c;

            }

            //updateWorld

            private function updateWorld(e:Event):void{


                if(left)
                {
                    //theSphere.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(-10,0));
                    theSphere.ApplyTorque(-3);
                }
                if(right)
                {
                    //theSphere.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(10,0));
                    theSphere.ApplyTorque(3);

                    //theSphere.ApplyTorque(0.5);

                }


                world.Step(1/30,10,10);
                world.ClearForces();

                for(var currentBody:b2Body=world.GetBodyList(); currentBody; currentBody=currentBody.GetNext())
                {
                    if(currentBody.GetUserData()!=null){
                        gameCanvas.x=320-currentBody.GetPosition().x*worldScale;
                        gameCanvas.y=240-currentBody.GetPosition().y*worldScale;
                        //gameCanvas.addChild(currentBody.GetUserData());
                        if(gameCanvas.x<=-realWidth+800){
                            nextHill=drawHill(5,realWidth,nextHill);
                        }

//This is where i set the position of the of the asset i created.
                        currentBody.GetUserData().asset.x=(currentBody.GetPosition().x*worldScale);
                        currentBody.GetUserData().asset.y=((currentBody.GetPosition().y+(50/worldScale))*worldScale);


                    }

                    if(currentBody.GetPosition().x*worldScale<(gameCanvas.x*-1)-640){
                        world.DestroyBody(currentBody);
                    }
                }
                world.DrawDebugData();
            }

            //keyPressed
            private function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case 37 :
                        left=true;
                        break;
                    case 39 :
                        right=true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            //keyReleased
            private function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case 37 :
                        left=false;
                        break;
                    case 39 :
                        right=false;
                        break;
                }
            }



        }//Class Ends here

    }//Package Ends here
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code

Comment: It's a ready code. I don't want others to type it and spend too much time on this.They can simply copy paste the code link an asset and run it. :)